# Umbraco - Getting Page elements by using pageId

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 6.0.1 I have created two pages first one is having page elements like Page Header, Body Text etc.
And I have created another page in which I want the page elements used in first page, there is no any parent child relationship between them.
So is it possible to get page elements of another page into a page of Umbraco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not appear so, but there is always a parent-child relationship in Umbraco.

To explain, each node you create in the content structure is created under a master node which has an ID of -1. So, all nodes are children of this node. Even if your two nodes are in two seemingly independent content branches, they are *always* related.

If your two nodes were both root nodes, from within a cshtml view you can access all root nodes like so:

```
@Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot()
```

You can then traverse through them like this:

```
@{
    var rootNodes = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot();

    var settingsNode = rootNodes.First(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "Settings");
    var homeNode = rootNodes.First(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "Homepage");
}
```

You can then access the properties on these nodes and display them in your view.

Finally, much of this information can be found here at http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/ and it is a great place to familiarise yourself with how it all knits together.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but I cant manage those relations, so I found a solution for getting page by pageId 

umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document currentDoc = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document(PageId);

umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property prop = currentDoc.getProperty( "MY_PROPERTY" );

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can get Page without relations, as mentioned in above comment
Also targeted page properties.

```
var currentDoc = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document(PageId);

umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property prop = currentDoc.getProperty( "MY_PROPERTY" );
```

Comment: There are two problems with this approach: 1) This is only ok if you know the ID of the page and the page is permanent. The problem with CMS-based sites is that pages get deleted and replaced. 2) It makes several calls to the database - one to retrieve the document and at least one to retrieve the properties. The better solution is to use the approach that queries the XML cache. See my answer and/or the Umbraco documentation.

Comment: Yes, the things you raised are right but If we are able to manage page names then we have also solution for getting pageId by using page name /// uQuery.GetNodesByName(pageName) /// and basically we are working on multilingual site so there are individual root node for each language. And in case of database calls, Yes your solution would be the best... Thanks